# Is there a way to change AWS ElastiCache Redis Version to 6.2?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

My ElastiCache Redis version is on 6.0.5. But I want to use 6.2. According to [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/supported-engine-versions.html) you can't specify the exact v6.x version.

I want to know if it's possible to upgrade it manually or something.

Comment: We have the same problem. We need version 6.0.6 for LPOS support but it's not possible to upgrade the engine version. Now we had no choice but run a redis container and maintain it on our own.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve looked into this and was unable to find a way to use ElastiCache with Redis 6.2. Instead, I have deployed Redis in docker with ECS and Fargate in a Redis 6.2 dockerfile. Not as turnkey as ElastiCache though, I’m afraid.